# How to tap a button in UI Automation which has only coordinates?

Tags: javascript, instruments, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I only have the coordinates of the button :

```
UIAButton:rect:{{253,27},{60,30}}
```

which I have stored in an array. I want to tap this button particularly without giving its coordinates so that it is generic for the remaining buttons.

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the coordinates instead of a reference to the object itself?

Comment: If the button is set up to be accessible it makes much more sense to call .tap() on the corresponding UIAElement than to try to make a generic tap that somehow doesn't work off of coordinates or reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like what is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14738389/2063546).

```
UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().tapWithOptions({tapCount: 1, tapOffset: {x: 0, y: 0});
```

You'd replace the zeros in `tapOffset` with your desired x and y values.